# Google Maps Geocoding API quota

Tags: google-maps

We have a valid license from Google and we have enabled the Google Maps Geocoding API. It seems that it set a quota of 2500 requests per day and if we reach this limit then we are banned. I thought that this quota is set for free usage only. Is this quota normal ?

Answer (score 3):

The 2500 limit, is for only while you don't pay, after then you can pay $0.50 per additional 1000 requests, up to 100,000, as you can see here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API having their own limitations.
Check  here: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/quotas?project=mintop
Google Maps API Quota for usage statistics and limitations. Google Maps API Quota Dashboard

Go for premium plan if you are having heavy usage.